# Why is bazel not picking up my header from external?

Tags: bazel

I have a problem when doing `bazel build //MyPackage:MyTarget`

```
fatal error: tls.h: No such file or directory
 #include <tls.h>
```

I tried everything:

```
#include <external/libressl/install/include/tls.h>
#include <libressl/install/include/tls.h>
#include <include/tls.h>
#include <tls.h>
```

Bazel query tells me that the dependency is there so it should be fine:

```
bazel query 'labels(hdrs, //MyPackage:MyTarget)'
@libressl//install:hdrs
```

Also the headers themselves definitely get picked up:

```
bazel query 'labels(hdrs, @libressl//install:hdrs)'
@libressl//install:include/tls.h
```

This is the target:

```
cc_library(
    name = "MyTarget",
    hdrs = [
        "@libressl//install:hdrs"
    ],
    srcs = [
        "test.cpp",
    ],
    deps = [
    "@libressl//install:libssl", 
    "@libressl//install:libtls",
    "@libressl//install:libcrypto"
    ],
    copts = [
    "-Iexternal/libressl/install/include"],
)
```

So what could be the problem? I can clearly see my external folder and the path is correct, I copy pasted it. Full path: `my-workspace/bazel-my-workspace-isolated/external/libressl/install/include/tls.h`

Answer (score 0):

I had to put the `"@libressl//install:hdrs"` into `deps`